# Draw raster on top of a Leaflet map

Tags: raster, leaflet, dem

I want to implement a raster layer on top of a Leaflet map that includes the following functionalities:

1. Digital Elevation Model (DEM) terrain height included in each raster cell
2. GPS-Track (I use [this plugin for GPS tracks](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-gps). Is there another one I should use?)
3. Assign a color to each raster cell that was visited by a GPS point.

What is the easiest way to go about this? Are there any better plugins I should use?

Comment: I think you should use QGIS and the plugin QGIS2WEB. You simply create your qgis project with the DEM Raster and the GPS Track. Then you should createa a new raster where pixels corresponding to the gps track will have a special color. Done that, the plugin QGIS2WEB does the rest and publishes your raster and vector data with leaflet (or openlayers)

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I would like to avoid any additional software like QGIS, though. Also the map should show a live GPS-tracking and assign a cell color while I'm outdoors with my tablet.